# PostgreSQL COPY FROM file vs STDIN

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, csv

I have spent a lot of time researching this and have not really found anything to explain this at all so I am hoping somebody here can help. I am currently writing a program to clean and input large amounts of data (potentially tens of GBs) into a Postgres table.

My current setup has me reading in and cleaning the original CSV data into a fresh CSV file before then running COPY FROM command to read in that fresh CSV file into the table.

There are some obvious problems with this, including basically reading the file 2-3 times, as well as double storage space required. It seems inefficient to read into a new file and then read that file into Postgres, instead of simply streaming it straight to STDIN of the Postgres shell and having that insert directly into the table.

If anyone has any experience dealing with at similar issue, did you find it faster/possible to simply stream a file to STDIN of Postgres? I am implementing this in Java, so any and all help I can get with this issue is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the `CopyManager` support from the JDBC driver: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html

Comment: I have been trying to use that, but haven't been able to figure out how to "stream" the data to the STDIN of Postgres, what I end up doing is just calling the copyIn function at the end of my cleaning and passing it the SQL statement as well as the fileReader which has opened my cleaned file. Do you have any sample code or explanation as to how I insert each CSV row into the STDIN as they come in from being cleaned?

Comment: `copyIn()` just takes a `Reader` as the parameter. Make your "cleaning code" implement that interface and then pass that to the CopyManager

Comment: maybe I am just misunderstanding the copyIn() method, but the method that we are referring to with a Reader object as a parameter returns a long, not a CopyIn object. So that leads me to believe, you need to have all of your data in the Reader when you make the cal, because it sounds like it makes one pass and that is it.

Comment: Am i just wrong when I say that? By the way, really appreciate your help

Comment: `copyIn()` returns the number of rows that were inserted. You don't need to have the data "in" the reader. Your class just needs to return the "cleaned" data in the `read()` method - it can actually stream it from there without the need to read everything into memory the same way e.g. `BufferedReader` or `FileReader` works

Comment: okay I think maybe I just don't know enough about the reader class. I guess then my follow up is, the cleaning is being done in parallel, so is there a ThreadSafe Reader object that I can return my clean data into that I can then pass into the copyIn() and stream that data to Postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream together, so you could read from source CSV file directly and then write to the inputStream which will be used in copyIn() Function.
Here is an example:

```
PipedInputStream is = new PipedInputStream();
PipedOutputStream os = new PipedOutputStream(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
BufferedReader fr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("path/to/file"));
```

Than read from `fr` and write to `bw`. I think you could write rest part of the codes. :)